# vscode, how can I use ITerm2 as my launch.json console externalTerminal on mac osx?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use `ITerm2` not the default terminal as the launch.json console external terminal.

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "server",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/server.ts",
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "outFiles": [
    "${workspaceRoot}/build/server.js"
  ],
  "console": "externalTerminal" //default, this open the default ternimal on mac osx.
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

settings.json-->`"terminal.external.osxExec": "Terminal.app"`, change it to `"terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app"`